# Detect merged cells in VBA Excel with MergeArea

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I'm having quite an issue with this one - I have to detect horizontally and vertically merged cells from an excel table. I have to store the first cell coords, and the lenght of the merged area. I iterate through the table with two for-cycles, line by line.

How can I use MergeArea property to detect the merged and non-merged areas?
If the cell is not merged, it should probably return empty range, however, this:

"If currentRange Is Nothing Then"

is not working at all. Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: First, why not update your question with the actual code you have questions about? If a cell is *not* merged then mergearea still returns a single-cell range, so you can't just check `If Not c.MergeArea Is Nothing`.  You need to check the number of rows/columns, and you can find the top-left cell using `c.MergeArea.Cells(1)`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There are several helpful bits of code for this.

Place your cursor in a *merged* cell and ask these questions in the Immidiate Window:

Is the activecell a merged cell?

```
? Activecell.Mergecells
 True
```

How many cells are merged?

```
? Activecell.MergeArea.Cells.Count
 2
```

How many columns are merged?

```
? Activecell.MergeArea.Columns.Count
 2
```

How many rows are merged?

```
? Activecell.MergeArea.Rows.Count
  1
```

What's the merged range address?

```
? activecell.MergeArea.Address
  $F$2:$F$3
```

Comment: according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822300(v=office.15).aspx) the MergeArea property returns the range object itself if it is **not** in a merged area.  So you should be able to use MergeArea without having to check MergeCells first.  Works in my code.

Answer (score 6):

While working with selected cells as shown by @tbur can be useful, it's also not the only option available.

You can use **Range()** like so:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").MergeCells Then
  Do something
Else
  Do something else
End If
```

Or:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1").MergeCells Then
  Do something
Else
  Do something else
End If
```

Alternately, you can use **Cells()**:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).MergeCells Then
  Do something
Else
  Do something else
End If
```