# Excel Javascript API - Check for merge cells

Tags: excel, office-js

I would like to query Excel for a range of cells and know whether there are merged cells within that range. I see that there is an API for merging cells and an API for unmerging cells. Does anyone know if it is possible to just check for merge cells?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you managed to query a range of cells yet? Have you installed the API? Here is a guide on how to do it in VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea You need to refer the the JS API guide https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/application and see if those methods and properties are supported

Answer (score 2):

Currently we don't have an API to query the state of merged cells.
Please log a feature request on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and we will take it into account for future API planning.

-Philip, Developer on the Office Extensibility team

Answer (score 0):

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getMergedAreasOrNullObject__

Note: This is still a WIP for me, would need a "isNull" check and I haven't adapted this for production code, but this should be a good starting point. I recommend examine the `mergedAreas` object if you need further details.

Here is how I did it:

```
async function Get_Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs(context, ws) { //test for Null
    var mergedAreas = ws.getUsedRange(true).getMergedAreasOrNullObject();
    mergedAreas.load(["areas"]);
    await context.sync()

    var Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs = []
    var arrlen = mergedAreas.areas.items.length
    for (var ai = 0; ai < arrlen; ai += 1) {
        var obj = mergedAreas.areas.items[ai]
        var rng_obj = {}
        rng_obj['worksheet'] = obj['address'].split("!")[0]
        rng_obj['rowIndex'] = obj['rowIndex']
        rng_obj['columnIndex'] = obj['columnIndex']
        rng_obj['rowCount'] = obj['rowCount']
        rng_obj['columnCount'] = obj['columnCount']
        Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs.push(rng_obj)
    }
    return Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs
}
```

---

```
var Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs = await Get_Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs(context,ws)
console.log('Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs:')
console.log(Merged_Areas_Arr_Of_Objs)
```

---

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
   [
      0: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         columnCount: 1,
         columnIndex: 0,
         rowCount: 3,
         rowIndex: 1,
         Symbol()_7.z1gk27bjwa1: undefined,
         Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)_j.z1gk27bjwa1: undefined,
         worksheet: "Sheet3"
      },
      1: { },
      2: { },
      3: { },
      length: 4
   ]
```