# How do I detect merged cells in a range from an Excel Javascript Add-In?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

In the Excel Javascript API, I see the methods on the the range class to merge and unmerge cells, but don't see properties that indicate if a cell is merged and how many rows and columns it encompasses. If there's not an explicit API to read this, does anyone know of a workaround - eg. detecting merge status indirectly or getting the range's underlying xml and parsing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Javascript API - Check for merge cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069208/excel-javascript-api-check-for-merge-cells)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample work around to select a range and merge the range, then check whether it's merge range or not :

```
    //get selected range and did merge
var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
range.merge();
await context.sync();

    // check whether the range is merged or not 
range.load();
await context.sync();
console.log(range["cellCount"]);

const str = range.address;
const colCount = range.columnCount;
const rowCount = range.rowCount;
console.log(colCount);
console.log(rowCount);
if (str) {
  const arr = str.split("!");
  console.log(arr[1]);
  if ((range["cellCount"] > 1 || range["colCount"] > 1 || range["rowCount"] > 1) && arr[1].indexOf(":") == -1) {
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    console.log("false");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't seem to be working when I try it, since single cell ranges are returning a cellCount of 1 even if they're the start of a merge. Also, I'd need to get the rowCount and columnCount rather than the cellCount to get the directions of the merge, right?

Comment: If I understand correct, if the range is merged, then it should be composed of more than one cells, or it won't be called merged range. And if you selected a merged range, the cell count should be >1, which I verified at both Win32 and Excel online. And for columnCount/ rowCount, you can also use them to track the merge direction. I edited the above sample code with selected range and you can replace cell count with column count or row count as your preference. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks for following up! I think the distinction is that I'm trying to determine _which_ of the cells in a range are merged together rather then whether the _entire_ range is merged. Any thoughts on how to determine that, for example, A2:B2 are merged together in a selected range of A1:G10?  The Google Sheets API has a Range.getMergedRanges() function that returns an array of ranges and I'm hoping there's a workaround for Excel that could get me to something similar.

Comment: We also provide the same new API now and now it's in preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getMergedAreasOrNullObject__

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, currently we don't have a API (in VBA, corresponding API is `Range.MergeCells`) to check the state of merged cells. you could try Ginger Jiang (from our team)'s workaround, if you know the original range address before merge.

If your scenario still not be able to unblock, I would suggest to submit your request on UserVoice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563 and upvote for this feature, we will add it to our backlog.

PS. it would be great if you could share us your scenario. Therefore we could see how we can unblock your scenario with existing APIs.

Thanks

Comment: @Reymond Lu - thanks! I'm trying to dynamically render an org chart diagram based on the sheet contents. For example, if a user has a range where A1:A2 is merged and populated and B1 and B2 are both populated, it should display as one large box above two smaller boxes. It seems like I should be able to build a list of the merges by looping through the cells in a range and loading the rowCount and columnCount for each of them, but those properties always return 1.

Comment: Thanks, I would suggest to submit this request in UserVoice and upvote this request. we will add this to our backlog.

Comment: I upvoted this request from two years ago: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34354747-merged-cell . While something like the Range.getMergedRanges() method in the Google Sheets API would be ideal, it would be great if there was a workaround that could be implemented quickly, even if it's just a way to return raw xml for the selected range that the client js has to parse.

Comment: Feature request (4114954) was created in our backlog, for the workaround, would you please try Ginger's answer?