# excel add-in api: how to know if a range or cell is merged or not?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

Looking through `node_modules\@types\office-js\index.d.ts` for ExcelApi, I did not find any way to know if a range or a cell is merged or not, any idea?

thanks a lot

Comment: You're right, I don't see it offhand (there is "merge" and "unmerge" methods, but I don't know if we have a way of *seeing* whether something is merged).  I've sent an email to the team about it.

Comment: In VBA [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076713/4717755) indicates the use of the `Mergecells` property. Not sure if it will work in your situatoin.

Comment: no, there is no Mergecells in js api

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, currently we don't have a API (in VBA, corresponding API is Range.MergeCells) to check the state of merged cells. I would suggest to submit your request for [merged cell](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34354747-merged-cell) in UserVoice and upvote for this feature, we will plan it based on the vote.

Thanks