# Counting merged cells as one with the COUNT IF function while also using other COUNT IF criteria

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I have used the following VBA module to count a list of items in a column on the basis of cell colour using the COUNT IF function:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
    Dim datax As range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

However, my list also contains merged cells, and while the above function works, it counts merged cells as the number of cells making up the merged cells (so for example, a merged cell made of 3 regular cells is counted as 3 in the list). If possible, I need a way to count merged cells as 1 cell while still maintaining the colour-coding counting.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Exactly how does `COUNTIF()` factor in here?  Your code only counts merged cells as a single cell, so it's not clear what the problem is...

Comment: @TimWilliams The COUNT IF function lets me count on the basis of cell colour, however, if a cell is merged and coloured then it won't count it as 1 cell it will count it as however many cells make up the merged cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat merged cells and not merged cells separately then add it all together :

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    Set D1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex

    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
            If datax.MergeCells Then
                D1(datax.MergeArea.Address) = datax.MergeArea.Address
            Else
                CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next datax

    CountCcolor = CountCcolor + D1.Count
End Function
```

Sources : [Here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1501-excel-count-merged-cells.html) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea)

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue :)