# Hide Multiple Columns Except Date Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA code to show only some columns between two dates which are input in other cells. Since Excel doesn't consider "Date 1" (annoying) as the content for all the merged cells it is not possible to use some "while" logic, which could be great here.

I've tried some things but they clearly don't work.

Context:
I have this currently in multiple sheets in a workbook and I wanted to have all the information in one sheet and the idea to keep it organized was to use a filter.

If someone has an idea for the code or another way to organize this, it would be very helpful.

Code I tried:

```
With ActiveSheet
    LastDate = .Cells("2", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set DDS = Range(.Cells(2, 11), .Cells(56, LastDate))
End With

For i = 1 To LastDate
    If DDS(1, i) = StartDate Then
        DDS.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        i = i + 22
        For j = i To LastDate
            If DDS(1, j) = EndDate Then
                For k = j To LastDate
                    If DDS(1, k) <> 0 And DDS(1, k) <> EndDate Then
                        j = k
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
                i = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Else
        DDS.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        i = i + 22
    End If
Next i
```

[image: Tables]

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to hide all of the columns that are merged into a single cell?

Comment: Could try this to identify Date 1 and continue with your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  You can check if a cell is part of a merged range by checking the `MergeCells` property of the cell and return the merged address using the `MergeArea.Address` property of the cell.

Comment: Along the lines of @DarrenBartrup-Cook 's comments, you might be able to do something like `MergeArea.Range("A1")` to grab the date for a merged area, but I'd like to think about this to see if there is a cleaner way to do this (if someone does not come up with a solution before I get to it :)

Comment: I want to input a Start and End Date and show only everything in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the below:

```
Function ShowDate(StartDate As Date, LastDate As Date)

Dim tVar As Variant, CurDate As Date, hideBoolean As Boolean

With ActiveSheet
    ' Get the date range, and the field ranges, and put into an array for easy manipulation
    tVar = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("2:3"))
End With

' For each column
For i = 1 To UBound(tVar, 2)
    ' If there is no field, then let's not do anything
    If Len(tVar(2, i)) = 0 Then GoTo SkipIt
    ' If there is a date, then make a note of it, otherwise make the top level equal to the current date
    If Not Len(tVar(1, i)) = 0 Then CurDate = tVar(1, i) Else tVar(1, i) = CurDate
    ' Figure out whether we want to hide the column or not.
    hideBoolean = (tVar(1, i) < StartDate) And (tVar(1, i) > LastDate)
    ' And finally hide or unhide that column
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = hideBoolean
SkipIt:
    Next i

End Function
```