# How to cycle through merged cells (and populate values from a one-dimensional array)?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find a way how to cycle through merged cells, e.g. using a For...Next loop.

I could only manage to make it work like this:

```
Cells(1,1).Select

For i=1 to 6
      Selection.Value = arrData(i)
      Selection.Offset(0,1).Select
Next i
```

I hate using `.Select` - but if I use `.Offset(0,i)` it won't move from merged cell to merged cell, but just the number of columns from the original cell.

For more detail - I am copying values from a *csv-like* format into a nicer formatted output sheet, that is then supposed to be exported with bunch of merged cells.

There are multiple sections to the sheet but within each section there is a known amount of cells per row.

My only working solution without `.Select` is to use `.Cells`

Example:

```
For row=0 to 12
   with rng.Offset(1,0)
      .cells(row+1,1)=arrdata(1+(row*6))
      .cells(row+1,3)=arrdata(2+(row*6))
      .cells(row+1,7)=arrdata(3+(row*6))
      .cells(row+1,9)=arrdata(4+(row*6))
      .cells(row+1,14)=arrdata(1+(row*6))
      .cells(row+1,16)=arrdata(1+(row*6))
   End with
Next row
```

but this is pretty ardous.

**EDIT**: Here is a screenshot:
[target area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4FHs.png)

The idea is that the amount of rows is completely flexible, depending on the transaction. So sometimes there is only one row, but can be anything really.

My code generates this section using relative references based on named ranges.

And then from the ugly sheet (where all information is stored in a single row) the values are fed into a one-dimensional array, then the array should be fed into the nice looking sheet.

If the sheet had no merged cells, the formula would look quite simple:

```
Dim i as integer, j as integer
Dim ws as worksheet: set ws = Worksheets("Printable")

'data array has already been filled with info in a linear order beforehand

k=1
For i=1 to item_qt 'number of cost items lines
   For j=1 to item_col 'number of detail columns (in this section)
      ws.Range("item_title").Offset(1,0).Cells(i,j).Value=data(k)
      k=k+1
   Next j
Next i
```

But because of the nature of this sheet - supposed to be printable and nicer on the eyes - I can't do that and have to find a way how to switch between the merged cells.

Hope this Edit cleared some things up.

I am also looking into the suggestions now to see if I can apply those somehow, but if anybody knows of something better, I am open for everything.

Comment: This might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea

Comment: It might be easier if you post an image of you worksheet and then explain what you are trying to do e.g. i want to jump to merged cell in C5 unmerge the range and and change the color of the cell to the right ... You can edit your anwer. There is an 'edit' button below your post.

Comment: added an edit - thank you for having a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're stepping through merged columns, you could use something like

```
For i = startColumn To endColumn
    If Cells(row,StartColumn).MergeArea.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        'Do Stuff
        i = i + Cells(row,StartColumn).MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
    End If
    Debug.Print i
Next i
```

This will test for merged columns and then jump to the next column after the merge.

**EDIT:**

Seeing your data structure added in your edit, you could incorporate the `MergeArea.Columns.Count` method into your `For j-Next j` loop like

```
k=1
For i=1 to item_qt 'number of cost items lines
   For j=1 to item_col 'number of detail columns (in this section) <-this will need to
                       'be the total number of columns, not just the number of 
                       'detail fields
      ws.Range("item_title").Offset(1,0).Cells(i,j).Value=data(k)
      j = j + ws.Range("item_title").Offset(1,0).Cells(i,j).MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
      k=k+1
   Next j
Next i
```

Comment: hey, that's an interesting approach! I will see if I can bend it to suit my project! thanks! btw, I have added an edit, to explain myself better - I don't words very good.

Comment: Added to my answer, hopefully this helps clarify how to add the `MergeArea` approach to the `simple` loop in your edit.

Comment: This works perfectly - I shall kiss your eyes. Thank you lots!

Comment: Haha, no eye kisses necessary. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

By searching for "excel find merged cells vba" Google comes up with:

How To Identify And Select All Merged Cells In Excel?
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/962-excel-select-merged-cells.html

```
Sub FindMergedcells()
'updateby Extendoffice 20160106
    Dim x As Range
    For Each x In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If x.MergeCells Then
            x.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

and

2 Practical Methods to Find Merged Cells in Your Excel
https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-practical-methods-find-merged-cells-excel/

```
Sub FindMerge()
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range(“A1:G13”)
        If cel.MergeCells = True Then
            ‘change the color to make it different
            cel.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: hey, thank you for responding so quickly! This is not quite what I am after, I added some more info and an image to try explain it a bit better