# How can i export merged cells in table from excel to word 2016 using a macro?

Tags: vba, office-2016, excel-tables, export-to-word

I try to use this method to export a table from excel to word, however i cannot export correctly because the merged cells appears unmerged.

But the problem is that the format does not include the merged cells, also i noticed that the customized colors are not copied correctly to word.

WordFormatting Required Boolean True formats the table using the formatting in the Word document. False formats the table according to the original Excel file.

```
objword.Selection.pasteexceltable False, False, True
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: To copy format you must for each cells in Excel copy format to correspondimg cell in Word. Any format property copy use self assignment operator.

Comment: About merge cells see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea) and megre corresponding word cells.