# VBA sorting Range Alphabetically

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

So i have Columns C tru J with data:

Last Names | first Name | Phone ...  etc

Im trying to sort at the end of a macro the whole Column C by Last Names alphabetically, Starting from C14 to C9999

i have this, have tried other codes but keep getting the same error:

```
Range("C14").CurrentRegion.Sort [C14], xlAscending
```

the **All merged cells must be the same size keeps** showing up, idk why, i have checked and i dont have any mergeded cells!!!

Please help.

Comment: If it says there are merged cells then there are. Check again. Also see [Detect merged cells in VBA Excel with MergeArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea) and [2 Practical Methods to Find Merged Cells in Your Excel](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-practical-methods-find-merged-cells-excel/) how to find them.

Comment: it returns

? Activecell.Mergecells
False

? Activecell.MergeArea.Columns.Count
 1 

? Activecell.MergeArea.Rows.Count
 1

Comment: Using Method #2 We couldn't find what you were looking for. click options for more ways to search. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Range` object has no worksheet specified. Therefore Excel is not using the worsheet you think it uses. So actually Excel tries to sort on a wrong worksheet and that has merged cells.

Never use `Range` without specifying the worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'specify your name

ws.Range("C14").CurrentRegion.Sort ws.Range("C14"), xlAscending
```

Also instead of `[C14]` use a proper referenece with worksheet `ws.Range("C14")`.

---

Edit according comment:

To sort only from C14 downwards use:

```
With ws.Range("C14").CurrentRegion
    .Resize(RowSize:=.Rows.Count - 14 + .Row - 1).Offset(RowOffset:=14 - .Row + 1).Sort ws.Range("C14"), xlAscending
End With
```

Comment: i have a "With Sheet8" at the beginning of the code, will that matter?

Comment: @JavyColón `Range("C14")` does not use the `With` statement nor does `[C14]`. `With` statement is only used if the statement starts with a dot like `.Range("C14")`. So `.Range("C14").CurrentRegion.Sort .Range("C14"), xlAscending` would work after a `With Sheet8`.

Comment: ok so the issue im having now is that is not starting at C14, it sorts everything starting from C1

Comment: Because `CurrentRegion` is very sloppy. If there is data above C14 it will be included in `ws.Range("C14").CurrentRegion` you can check it with `Range("C14").CurrentRegion.Select` so you see what actually will be used for `.Sort`. See my edited answer for a solution.