# Find closest cell with data to the right and use it for calculus

Tags: excel, vba

I am now working on this file that handles all the shipments for my company. Here is how it should work:

- User press a button that shows a Userform
- User fills in the userform with the code of the parts shipped and the quantity and press command button to
  confirm
- The macro then finds the code previously inserted in the column containing all codes for the parts
  (i only need the row for the next steps)
- The macro then moves to the right until it finds the first order in the row
- The macro subtracts the quantity from the order and if the order is fulfilled cancels it and moves to the
  next one

There is no particular error in the code, but it wont work,
here is the code i have used :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cell As Variant


'TEXTBOX1 IS WHERE YOU INPUT THE CODE TO CHECK FOR IN COLUMN C

Set cell = Sheets("TEST").Range("C6:C42").Find(What:=TextBox1, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not cell Is Nothing Then

Line1:  'USED FOR LOOPING IF VALUE IS SMALLER THEN TEXTBOX2 (IN TEXTBOX2 YOU INSERT THE QUANTITY SHIPPED)

' GET CLOSEST VALUE TO THE RIGHT BUT DOESNT WORK

    If Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Value2 >= TextBox2 Then
        Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Value2 = Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Value2 - TextBox2
        
' IF THERE ARE NO MORE PARTS IN THAT ORDER THEN ELIMINATE IT (ELIMINATES QUANTITY,DATE AND PURCHASE ORDER)

    If Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Value2 = 0 Then
    Range(Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight), Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)).ClearContents
    End If
        
'IF I SHIP MORE PARTS THAN WHAT THE ORDER RQUIRES CANCEL THAT ORDER AND MOVE TO NEXT ONE

    ElseIf Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Value2 < TextBox2 Then
    
        TextBox2 = TextBox2 - Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Value2
        
        Range(Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight), Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Offset(0,    2)).ClearContents
    
    GoTo Line1 'FOR LOOPING
    
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is a picture of the excel sheet :[image]

Comment: If I may suggest, if you dim cell as range, you can use cell instead of `range(cell.address)`. Try to step run in and make a test code line to check before the IF code ... something like this : `cell.End(xlToRight).select` ---> does it select a correct cell ? `testVal = cell.End(xlToRight).Value2` ---> does testVal give a correct value in the locals window ? if it does, `dif = testVal - TextBox2.value` does dif give a correct positive value in the locals window? Also, I see that you merged two cells for the code of product Q, causing `cell.End(xlToRight).select` will never go to cell K21.

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is too broad (as it basically requires a responder to recreate your scenario and test it for you). Suggest doing your own testing (as karma suggests). That way, you can identify the problem, and possible solve it yourself, or at least put you in a position to post a more specific question regarding what's not working.

Comment: Thanks @karma, your suggestion helped me figure out the error and made the code much easier to read. If you make an answer i will mark it as correct

Comment: @karma i have another question, I have merged the cells for code product Q because i have 2 orders in the same month so i needed 2 rows. Is there a way for me to check if the cell containing the code is merged and then choose which row i want to use from the ones merged in the code cell. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea. So you can check the cell before the `If Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Value2 >= TextBox2` whether it's merged or not, and if merge just make an input box asking the user which nth row of the `cell.end(xltoright)` is wanted.