# Excel VBA, I need a way to skip merged cells and continue loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that runs through a data range of sheet8 and then transfers data into sheet 10 if it meets set criteria
its working well. I have am method of detecting merged cells which works well however the second IF statement will then run regardless of whether the data on sheet8 matches the set critiera?
any help would be great

```
    myvalue = Sheet8.Range("c2").Value
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet10.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim II As Integer
lRow = lRow + 1
  For II = 46 To 145
If Sheet8.Cells(II, 35).MergeCells = True Then
Else
  If Sheet8.Cells(II, 44).Value = myvalue & Sheet8.Cells(II, 35).Value <> "" Then
  Sheet10.Range("N" & lRow).Value = Sheet8.Cells(II, 35).Value
  Sheet10.Range("O" & lRow).Value = Sheet8.Cells(II, 36).Value
  Sheet10.Range("P" & lRow).Value = Sheet8.Cells(II, 37).Value
  Sheet10.Range("Q" & lRow).Value = Sheet8.Cells(II, 38).Value
  Sheet10.Range("R" & lRow).Value = Sheet8.Cells(II, 39).Value
  End If
End If
lRow = lRow + 1
  Next II
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea

Comment: Try also checking (before the actual (`If`) condition: `If not Sheet8.Cells(II, 44).MergeCells and not Sheet8.Cells(II, 35).MergeCells  Then`. And replace `&` in the existing condition, using `And` instead...

Comment: I've updated the code above with the ability to detect merged cells which works however the code will then run through all iterations regardless if they meet the criteria or not.